# What SEDE queries do you use?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, clean-up

I have been playing around with [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) lately. Any interesting queries you found and care to share?

Answer (score 4):

This is a small list of [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) queries I've compiled for my run towards the elusive [Marshal badge](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/94/marshal):

**Duplicates**

- [Find suggested duplicates that haven't led to question closure](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/2036/find-suggested-duplicates-that-havent-led-to-question-closure)
- [Find suggested duplicates that haven't led to question closure in a tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/2037/find-suggested-duplicates-that-havent-led-to-question-closure-in-a-tag)

**Controversial posts**

- [Most controversial posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/18/most-controversial-posts)

**Self answers**

- [Forum style questions - multiple self answers from asker](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1950/forum-style-questions-multiple-self-answers-from-asker)
- [Recent self answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1949/recent-self-answers)
- [You're probably doing it wrong (Questions with Multiple Answers by the OP)](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1844/youre-probably-doing-it-wrong-something-to-flag)
- [Not accepted self answers with negative votes](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1595/not-accepted-self-answers-with-negative-votes)
- [Recent Not accepted self answers with negative votes](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1662/recent-not-accepted-self-answers-with-negative-votes)

**Not an answer**

- [Posts that could be marked as 'not an answer' to help get the Marshal badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1818/posts-that-could-be-marked-as-not-an-answer-to-help-get-the-marshal-badge)
- [Seek and Destroy: Comments with the phrase "not an answer"](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1636/seek-and-destroy-comments-with-the-phrase-not-an-answer)
- [Something to Flag "Not an answer" in the body of an answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1816/something-to-flag-not-an-answer-in-the-body-of-an-answer)
- [Answers With Questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1741/answers-with-questions)
- [Find Something to Flag 1](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1300/find-something-to-flag-1) (small answers with links)
- [Find "me too" (so-called) answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/2008/find-me-too-so-called-answers)
- [Finding bad answers through comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1925/finding-bad-answers-through-comments)

**Comments**

- [Downvote Comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/2053/downvote-comments) (all those -1 comments)
- [Find obsolete "should be wiki" comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/2006/find-obsolete-should-be-wiki-comments)

Comment: Now you've tempted me to unvote you for moderator, so you still have a shot at this badge!

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Now that I think of it, becoming a moderator is not as rare as getting the Marshal badge... :)